# Is it possible to store and retrieve a container (e.g. std::vector) in an std::any variable?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, stdany, anycast

I would like to have heterogenous map in C++ for my unit test values.
Other threads recommended the use of std::any with any_cast for this purpose.
This works well for primitive types like int and double but I fail to retrieve the value if I use a std::vector.

My code looks like this:

```
    std::map<std::string, std::any> expected = {
        { "getInt", 1 },
        { "getDouble", 1.0 },
        { "getVector", std::vector<int> { 1, 2 } },
    }
    
    int getInt = std::any_cast<int>(expected["getInt"])
    double getDouble= std::any_cast<double>(expected["getDouble"])
```

So far the code works as expected, even though the need for any_cast feels convoluted coming from newer languages.
But if I try to do the same for a vector it fails:

```
    std::vector<int> getVector= std::any_cast<std::vector>(expected["getVector"])
```

Is there a way to retrieve an aggregate from a std::any value?

Comment: The term "aggregate" have a very special meaning in C++, and not every container or structure is an aggregate. For example `std::array<...>` is an aggregate, but `std::vector<...>` is not. See the definitions of an aggregate [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Definitions).

Comment: `std::vector` is not a type. It's a type template. If you use an actual type it works. And if you find the repetition of the type convoluted (with which I and others agree!) you don't have to do that: just use `auto` to declare the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the type of the vector in the `std::any_cast`.
Code:

```
std::vector<int> getVector = std::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(expected["getVector"]);
```